# vs code 1.20 - intellisense not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I'm new to VS Code and coding in general. Please bear with me.

I've been using Monodevelop for Unity C# coding since the start. I've switched over to VS Code, which I love. It's faster to load up and more "fun" to use.

I was running VS Code 1.19.3 recently and decided to upgrade to 1.20. But after upgrading I seem to have lost the autocomplete function, also some things are missing now.

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_thank-you

- In 1.19.3 I could type "pri" and it'll autocomplete "private"

  - In 1.20 I type "pri" and there's no autocomplete suggestion. But typing "publ" will get suggestions for "public"
- In 1.19.3 I could type a C# script "Playe" and it'll give me
  suggestions for "Players"

  - In 1.20 I type "Playe" and VS code has no suggestions for me.

Also I seem to be getting this error now:

> Target: d:\ProjectY\ProjectX.sln
>
> [ERROR] Error: spawn cmd ENOENT

ANy help would be appreciated

Comment: In regards to the ENOENT error, is `C:\Windows\System32` a part of your path environment variable? I'm guessing that OmniSharp is attempting to use cmd to start it's daemon and failing, so you have no intellisense provider to connect to.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late response. I gave up in the end and just installed Community.. (Yes I know) .. but for a newb like me, it was easier to set up. It's REALLY slow to load up, but at least it has all the features pre-installed. For me this is unfortunately the better way. Thanks for replying tho. Hope it helps others.